# ListView Component of React Desktop : Issue rendering List Items from an Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, rendering

I have an electron app which uses React for UI rendering, am trying to use [React-Desktop library](https://reactdesktop.js.org/docs/mac-os/list-view) to build a macOSX like application in Electron.

In my ListView component there is a state which is an array of json objects. I am trying to loop through the array and render list items, but there is a rendering problem. The details would not show up in my view once state is updated. The console log output works just fine. 
I suspect this has to do something with the list view, if i try to render individual items using `{this.renderItem(this.state.value[0].ID)}` in my jsx it works perfectly. However my goal is to populate these items using loop

```
  <ListView background="#f1f2f4" width="500" height="700">
    <ListViewHeader>
      <Text size="11" color="#696969">Order by name</Text>
    </ListViewHeader>
    <ListViewSection header={this.renderSectionHeader('Containers')}>
      {this.state.value.length == 0 ? "": this.state.value.forEach(element => {
          console.log(element.ID) //this works
          this.renderItem(element.ID, "some content") //nothing shows up


      })}
    </ListViewSection>
    <ListViewSeparator/>
    <ListViewSection header={this.renderSectionHeader('Images')}>
      {this.renderItem('Item 4', 'This is the fourth item.')}
      {this.renderItem('Item 5', 'This is the fifth item.')}
      {this.renderItem('Item 6', 'This is the sixth item.')}
    </ListViewSection>
    <ListViewFooter>
      <Text size="11" color="#696969">Status</Text>
    </ListViewFooter>
  </ListView>



  renderItem(title, info) {
    return (
      <ListViewRow
        onClick={() => this.setState({ selected: title })}
        background={this.state.selected === title ? '#d8dadc' : null}
      >



        <Text color="#414141" size="13">{info}</Text>
      </ListViewRow>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `forEach` [which is not returning anything](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters).
Try it with [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and you will get a new array of your items.
**Don't forget the `return` keyword**

```
this.state.value.map(element => {
  console.log(element.ID) //this works
  return this.renderItem(element.ID, "some content")
})
```